# How does model inheritance work in Django models?

Tags: python, django

Here are my models:

```
class OdishGovtJobs(models.Model):
    start_date        = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_date         = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    post_name         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    education         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    more_info         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    requirement_board = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type              = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Odisha Govt Jobs"

class AndamanNicoborGovtJobs(OdishGovtJobs):
    pass

    def __str__(self):
        return "Andaman Nicobor Govt Jobs"
```

I wants all the fields of the first and second model to be same, but I get the following errors:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What's the specific error that you're seeing? (You don't need to `pass` in your second class. Its body isn't empty: it contains a `__str__` method.)

Comment: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/soubhagya/Desktop/carrier-circle/backend/db/models.py", line 64, in <module>
    class AndamanNicoborGovtJobs(OdishGovtJobs):
  File "/home/soubhagya/Desktop/carrier-circle/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 208, in __new__
    base.__name__,
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'start_date' in class 'AndamanNicoborGovtJobs' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'OdishGovtJobs'.

Comment: this is a strange error, except for the `pass`, this should work. Have you tried `python manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: @SoubhagyaPradhan did my answer solve your problem, if you can you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define the base model OdishGovtJobs as abstract model ref [Abstract base classes¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

So your updated code will should look like this:

```
class OdishGovtJobs(models.Model):
    start_date        = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_date         = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    post_name         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    education         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    more_info         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    requirement_board = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type              = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return "Odisha Govt Jobs"
```

Also as per the design you want to impelemet your base model whould be named as **GovtJobs** instead and OdishGovtJobs etc. should inherit from it.